# Item builder executes 1 items instead of 7 items

Tags: flutter, rest

I'm fetching data from an weather API. There is a section weekly forecast. In my API link there are 7 Day's forecast data. But when I try to fetch forecast data using item builder there shows only 1 day's forecast instead of 7 days. I think model and functions are ok but I don't know why it's happening.

Here is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:weather_api/api%20integration/helper/weatherHelper.dart';
import 'package:weather_api/api%20integration/model/weatherModel.dart';
import 'package:weather_api/components/functions.dart';

class dailyUpdate extends StatelessWidget {
  dailyUpdate({super.key, required this.searchText});
  String searchText;
  weatherClass weatherObj = weatherClass();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: weatherObj.fetchWeather(searchText),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          WeatherModel? dailyUpdate = snapshot.data;
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: dailyUpdate?.forecast?.forecastday?.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 65, 65, 64),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Image.network(
                            'https:' +
                                dailyUpdate!.forecast!.forecastday![index].day!
                                    .condition!.icon
                                    .toString(),
                            width: 60,
                          ),
                          customText(
                              DateFormat('EEEE, MMMM d').format(DateTime.parse(
                                  dailyUpdate.forecast!.forecastday![index].date
                                      .toString())),
                              color: Colors.white),
                          customText(
                              dailyUpdate.forecast!.forecastday![index].day!
                                  .condition!.text
                                  .toString(),
                              color: Colors.white),
                          customText(
                              dailyUpdate.forecast!.forecastday![index].day!
                                      .maxtempC!
                                      .round()
                                      .toString() +
                                  ' / ' +
                                  dailyUpdate.forecast!.forecastday![index].day!
                                      .mintempC!
                                      .round()
                                      .toString(),
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          );
        }
        else if(snapshot.hasError){
          print("Location Not Found");
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Json URL : [Click here](http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=82e81a1ce073468eb27184736233006&days=7&q=barisal)

Executed Code :

[Executed Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH5yx.png)

Comment: Where do you use dailyUpdate widget?

Comment: Have you ensured that you send `days=7` as a param in the API Url? Because if you didn't set the params `days`, it seems that the API would return only 1 data for forecast day.

Comment: @AnisAlibegić i called daiyUpdates on main.dart page

Comment: @AfandiYusuf yes... url contains 7 days forecast... you can check the url which i provided

Comment: Can you provide the fetch weather function so we can take a peek on the request you are trying to send?